# Fujitsu LifeBook P1510D Touchscreen On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-netbook, touchscreen, tablet

I recently received a Fujitsu Lifebook P1510D and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. So far, it is working well but I cannot seem to get the touchscreen to work. I've searched the forums and I cannot find any references to Ubuntu 14.04 or Trusty Tahr. Any help would be appreciated. I am currently using XFCE.